# Creating a class and using a constructor in C++ (assignment)

Tags: c++, class, visual-c++, constructor, visual-c++-2017

For an assignment, I have to create a movie class that contains the name of the movie, the MPAA rating, the number of people that rated it from 1 to 5, find the accumulated value for each of the ratings and the average value.

I'm mainly having trouble with the constructor and the class. I'm trying to make it take an string (And I got that part somewhat right). I'm getting a few errors on line 77 and line 83. I am also stuck since I don't know what steps I should take next. I will appreciate any help possible.

Here is what I got so far:

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <string>
    // Required headers
    using namespace std;

    //Class movie starts
    class Movie {
    public:
    void SetMovieName(string moviename);
    // Function to set the name of the movie
    // moviename = movie; later on

    string GetMPAAR();
    //function to return the MPAA rating

    int amountofratingsof1() const;
    //function to return the number of people that rated the movie as a 1
    int amountofratingsof2() const;
    //function to return the number of people that rated the movie as a 2 
    int amountofratingsof3() const;
    //function to return the number of people that rated the movie as a 3
    int amountofratingsof4() const;
    //function to return the number of people that rated the movie as a 4 
    int amountofratingsof5() const;
    //function to return the number of people that rated the movie as a 5

    int average() const;
    //function to return the average value of all ratings

    std::string Movies(string moviename = "Gavecube: The Movie");
    //constructor to set the movie



    private:
    string Movie; //variable to store the name of the movie
    int peoplethatrated1; // variable to store the number of people that rated 1
    int peoplethatrated2; // variable to store the number of people that rated 2
    int peoplethatrated3; // variable to store the number of people that rated 3
    int peoplethatrated4; // variable to store the number of people that rated 4
    int peoplethatrated5; // variable to store the number of people that rated 5
};

//implementation file:

void Movie::SetMovieName(const string moviename) {
    //function below checks if it is a string or not
    if (!cin) {
        cout << "Not a valid input. Please restart." << endl;
    }
}

int Movie::amountofratingsof1()const {

}

int Movie::amountofratingsof2()const {

}
int Movie::amountofratingsof3()const {

}
int Movie::amountofratingsof4()const {

}
int Movie::amountofratingsof5()const {

}

//constructor
std::string Movie(string moviename) {
    SetMovieName(moviesname)
}


int main()
{
    Movie Movies("Hello"); 



    return 0;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You're going to get down-voted because we also don't know what "steps you should take next". Good questions have a clear answer, rather than a discussion.

Comment: Also, you did not create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: "_I'm getting a few errors on line 77 and line 83. I am also stuck since I don't know what steps I should take next._" Well, you can start by reading the errors, and fixing them, if you, really, have them..

Comment: get rid of `#include <string.h>` because nothing you've shown needs it.  If you did need it in a C++ file, you would call it `#include <cstring>`

Comment: You prefix all the member functions with `Movie::` but missed that for the constructor. And you also have to check for "movie" or "movies" in a few places.

Comment: `int peoplethatrated1;int peoplethatrated2;`... You could have saved yourself a lot of grief by just using `int peoplethatrated[5];` instead of 5 different variables.

Comment: Your constructor should not have a return type. When defined outside of the class declaration, it should be Movie::Movie(string moviename) {
    SetMovieName(moviename);
}

Comment: You also need to have return values for all your amountofratingsX() functions where X is 1,2,3,4,5.

Comment: Thanks guys. I kind of figured it out after a few hours of reading. And I apologize for the MCV (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable).

Answer (score 0):

For constructors, they aren't like a normal function. They have no return type, not even `void`. Within the constructor, if you can use member initiation, you should. [Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/) is a pretty good explanation of constructors if you go down to the `Constructors` section. In general it should look like:

```
ClassName (parameter par1, ...) : mem1(par1), ...{}
```

where `mem1` is the data member corresponding to `par1`. Further down in [the link](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/) is the member initiation section that covers how to do that. Once you get the constructor setup, you should finish with your member function definitions in whatever order you want then test and debug like you would any other program. Test edge cases and invalid numbers if you need to do error-checking.